# Cannot analyze option in for loop in bash script

Tags: bash, for-loop

I write a shell script but I cannot analyze options. Script can get -t option or -i option and both options need parameter.
This is the script. Environment is Centos6.7 bash version 4.1.2

```
$ cat opt_test.sh
#!/bin/bash

## Analyze options
for opt in $*
do
  case ${opt} in
    '-t' )
      opt_t_flag=0
      opt_t_value=$2
      shift 2
      ;;
    '-i' )
      opt_i_flag=0
      opt_i_value=$2
      shift 2
      ;;
    * )
      echo Usage: ${0##*/} [-t time] [-i ip_address]
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done

## Check value
echo opt_t_value: ${opt_t_value}
echo opt_i_value: ${opt_i_value}
```

I executed it but it could not work...

```
$ ./opt_test.sh -t 1200
Usage: opt_test.sh [-t time] [-i ip_address]

$ ./opt_test.sh -t 1200 -i 127.0.0.1
Usage: opt_test.sh [-t time] [-i ip_address]
```

I expected that the first result is `opt_t_value: 1200 \n opt_i_value:`, second one is `opt_t_value: 1200 \n opt_i_value: 127.0.0.1`

**[Question1]**
Why this script can not work?

**[Question2]**
What part should I modify to analyze option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Answer for Q1]**
I write following short script and I test it.

```
$ cat for_test.sh
#!/bin/bash

for opt in $*
do
  echo opt: ${opt}
  shift 2
  echo '$*': $*
done

$ ./for_test.sh 1 2 3 4 5 6
opt: 1
$*: 3 4 5 6
opt: 2
$*: 5 6
opt: 3
$*:
opt: 4
$*:
opt: 5
$*:
opt: 6
$*:
```

Maybe `shift 2` affects only "$*" in for loop. Workaround is using `while` loop instead of `for`. `While` loop looks like work correctly.

```
$ cat while_test.sh
#!/bin/bash

while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
  opt=$1
  echo opt: ${opt}
  shift 2
  echo '$*': $*
done

$ ./while_test.sh 1 2 3 4 5 6
opt: 1
$*: 3 4 5 6
opt: 3
$*: 5 6
opt: 5
$*:
```

So I modified first script like following. This is **[Answer for Q2]**

```
$ cat cat opt_test.sh
#!/bin/bash

while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
  opt=$1
  case ${opt} in
    '-t' )
      opt_t_flag=0
      opt_t_value=$2
      shift 2
      ;;
    '-i' )
      opt_i_flag=0
      opt_i_value=$2
      shift 2
      ;;
    * )
      echo Usage: ${0##*/} [-t time] [-i ip_address]
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done

echo opt_t_value: ${opt_t_value}
echo opt_i_value: ${opt_i_value}
```

It looks like work correctly. (Although there is no error handling...)

```
$ ./opt_test.sh -t 1200 -i 127.0.0.1
opt_t_value: 1200
opt_i_value: 127.0.0.1
```